# MapBox / Leaflet / maybe jQuery - binding a function to a popup that is called on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, mapbox

I'm trying to create an empty popup in the MapBox API that isn't filled until it is clicked. Using jQuery as well, I tried:

```
L.marker([coordinates]).bindPopup("").on('click', function(){alert('Hello StackOverflow'!)}));
```

This works, every marker I click on opens a friendly JavaScript alert. However, instead of an alert, I'd much rather call the popup's setContent() and update() methods. However, this does not work:

```
L.marker([coordinates]).bindPopup("").on('click', function(){ this.setContent("Hello StackOverflow!"); this.update();}));
```

I get an error message that this.setContent is not a function.

Anyone know what to do? I'm trying to call an ASP.NET controller method, which should return the HTML and JavaScript I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself. What I did wrong in my code was trying to set the content of the marker itself, while I was supposed to set the content of the popup bound to it. This worked for me:

```
var popup = L.popup().on('open', function () { this.setContent("Hello StackOverflow!"); this.update(); });       
        markerArray.push(L.marker(coordinates).bindPopup(popup));
```